# Custom Python Transpiler

Tags: python, assembly, robotics, transpiler, lego-mindstorms

I am participating in FLL (FIRST LEGO League, a Mindstorm robotics competition) and this year they piloted a program allow teams to code in Python. I have found a way to disassemble the LEGO Mindstorm block language to the LEGO assembly code. How can I write a python-based transpiler to convert the python to the assembly code or vice versa? I will try to upload the assembly code.

Many thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: maybe ask author of [Transcrypt](https://www.transcrypt.org/) which transpiles Python to JavaScript

Comment: Python is compiled to bytecode (.pyc files). Use that and translate each instruction to an equivalent set of RCX bytecodes. You will also need any other metadata and data (e.g. constants).